# Does Stream have a 4 GB limit in UWP?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, stream

I need to write a very large file from my UWP application and I tried to do it by using a code similar to the following one:

```
private async void btnWriteData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FolderPicker pick = new FolderPicker();
        pick.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bin");
        StorageFolder folder = await pick.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        StorageFile oFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("ThisIsMyTest.bin");
        long totBytes = 0;
        using (var oStream = await oFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4194304];
            long i = 0;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            while (i <= 8589934592){
                rnd.NextBytes(buffer);
                totBytes += buffer.Length;
                Debug.WriteLine("totBytes: " + totBytes.ToString()+"/8789934592");
                
                await oStream.WriteAsync(buffer,0,(int)buffer.Length);
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Stop!");
   }
```

When I click the button associated to this event, I watch the progress of the operation.
The destination folder is on a drive with plenty of free space but when totBytes reaches 4.294.967.296 bytes written, the application rises a System.Exception stating that there isn't enough free space (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070070).
This is the stacktrace:

```
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.<WriteToUnderlyingStreamAsync>d__62.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MyApp.MainPage.<btnWriteData_Click>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\Users\matte\Documents\projectx\Windows10\MyApp\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 151
```

Am I doing anything wrong?
Is there a way to write a file larger than 4 GB by using streams?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind. You aren’t using FAT32 or are you?

Comment: No, of course. I'm on NTFS.

Comment: There's a few things that could be cleaned up, but specifically your not doing anything with `i` except declaring it, nothing more. This is a huge issue as your `while` loop depends on it, `while (i <= 8589934592)` this will always be true...

Comment: Yes, I know that because it's just a code to check if I could go beyond 4 GB.

Comment: Could you please tell me what Solution Platforms your project uses? You could try to switch to x64 platform to test your project.